# How can i make selenium to parse every network request?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to capture all requests with their responses using this code

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}

driver.get("<URL>")

def log_filter(log_):
    return (
        # is an actual response
        log_["method"] == "Network.responseReceived"
        # and json
        and "json" in log_["params"]["response"]["mimeType"]
    )


#sys.stdout = open('C:\\Users\\Zile\\Videos\\mhm\\output.txt', 'wt')

sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'wt')

for log in filter(log_filter, logs):
    request_id = log["params"]["requestId"]
    resp_url = log["params"]["response"]["url"]
    print(f"Caught {resp_url}")
    print(driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
        "Network.getResponseBody", {"requestId": request_id}))
```

It works great and it saves into txt file everything but the problem is it justs saves responses that have simillar domain to the driver.get, if url is google.com he will parse everything that google sended not other ones.
How can i make him to parse everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browsermob proxy for this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from browsermobproxy import Server

server = Server("/path/to/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy))
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
proxy.new_har("request")
```

Now to your driver you can add the proxy and then save all the details in a .har file.
To filter the records from .har file you can use the python-har.
This will filter the records for you according to the url.

```
from haralyzer import HarPage
har_page = HarPage(har_data=har_data)
print(har_page.entries[0])       # HAR Entry dict of first entry
print(har_page.entries[:2])      # List of HAR Entry dicts of first two entries
print(har_page.media_urls)       # List of all media URLS across all entries
print(har_page.html_urls)        # List of all HTML document URLS across all entries
print(har_page.other_urls)       # List of all non-HTML, non-media URLS across all entries
print(har_page.all_urls)         # Combined list of all URLs across all entries
print(har_page.all_js_urls)      # List of all JS URLs loaded across all entries
print(har_page.all_css_urls)     # List of all CSS URLs loaded across all entries
print(har_page.all_image_urls)   # List of all image URLs loaded across all entries
print(har_page.all_font_urls)    # List of all font URLs loaded across all entries
print(har_page.all_other_urls)   # List of all other URLs loaded across all entries
print(har_page.size)             # Total number of bytes comprising all entries
```

Comment: i get problem saying har_data is not defined